# React 18 with StrictMode shows blank screen

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I upgraded my react application to react `18.2.0` and I start application using `react-dom/client` as in documentation.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

But now when I start application I just see **blank (white) screen** and **there are no errors or warnings in console**, therefore I have no idea what is wrong.

When I remove StrictMode, then everything looks fine and application is rendered.

How can I find out what happened?

Comment: Might be the result of some underlying issue. https://twitter.com/reactjs/status/1509729057541341184

Comment: Thanks but thats not very helpful since it doesn't point any issues (no errors in console)

Comment: The post doesn't say anything about errors in console. It just states that due to the revamped nature of `StrictMode` nad it being "stricter", upgraded projects may not initially work.

Comment: Yeah but it also states that if it doesn't work with StrictMode, we can turn it off and address issues at our own pace. But what issues?

Comment: Well that's a good question, I'm assuming it can be any number of things. I guess the best we could hope for is for some user who has had the same issue to point you in the right direction. Even though the problem he had might not be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by upgrading `mobx` state management library.

Answer (score 0):

I was in exactly the same situation as the original poster and in my case, the fix was to upgrade `react-redux` to v8.